# CentOS 7/VMware Hang on Boot ([sda] Assuming drive cache: write through)

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-workstation

I am new in Linux. i use CentOS 7 (CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso) in VMware workstation 9. Host system is windows 8.
i was trying to install the update. when i restart it hang during boot.

it show only:

```
[ 2.356414] sd 0.0.0.0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

How i solve it.

[image]

Comment: This is just a warning and should not interfere with the normal boot of the VM. Hit escape to see the boot process and see where is it hanging (maybe it's just a bit slow...)

Comment: Hi sir, nothing is happen when press escape..

Comment: any help to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

The guest OS is returning a right message as the virtual disk does not have write-back cache. You should press the escape as soon as it boots up.